# From listbox to word table

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I want to make a program witch put items from ListBox to word table.
How can I put items from listbox to word table? I have 10 listboxes (1 for each column) so I need table with 10 columns and 30 rows.

1 more question. Can I insert as header of this doc a text? For example -> Document number 21 as header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` to your project, it is under the Extensions tab:

[image]

This code will generate a document, create a table, and just populate the table with the string `hello`.  I assume that you know how to read data from your listboxes, so you should be able to easily adapt this code to do that:

```
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim word As New Word.Application()
        word.Visible = True

        Dim doc = word.Documents.Add()
        Dim table = doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Tables.Add(doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range, 30, 10)

        For i As Integer = 0 To 9
            table.Cell(i, i).Range.Text = "hello"
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'Microsoft.Office.Interlop.Word' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

Comment: Did you add the reference?

Comment: I can't find Microsoft.Office.Interlop.Word in reference. (I search both .net and com).
Then I click Browse tab and try to run WINWORD.exe, it's say that This app can't be added.